# Multiple selection in C# DropDownListFor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sumoselect.js

How can I get multiple selection values here? I can choose them, but only one is sent as request. For multiple selection I use this script:
http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2016/03/multiselect-dropdownlist-using-jquery.html

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.FossilType, new SelectList(Model.Filter.FossilsTypesOptions, "Name", "Name"), new { @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "Placeholder", @class = "SlectBox"})
```

`FossilType` is a list of strings, `Filter` is a part of model containing it.

Comment: Can you post that value which you are getting after selecting multiple options? Also post jQuery code you have written.

Comment: I made a mistake in a description. `FossilType` is a string in the `SelecList` and the `FossilsTypesOptions` is a list, containing all of possible fossil types.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                window.asd = $('.SlectBox').SumoSelect({ csvDispCount: 4 });
                $("".ddlMultiSlectBox).SumoSelect({ csvSepChar: '|' });
            });
        </script>`
Here is a javascript code I took from http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2016/03/multiselect-dropdownlist-using-jquery.html. While choosing Diamond, Gold, Ruby I get only Diamond.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will get comma(default separator) separated string in your model property FossilType. You can split it with ',' and get all selected items.

You can also provide your custom separator in setting like:

```
$('.ddlMultiSlectBox).SumoSelect({ csvSepChar: '|' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue. The problem was actually caused by my controller. In this case, I should have written like this:

```
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.FossilTypes,
new SelectList(Model.Filter.FossilsTypesOptions, "Name", "Name"),
new { @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "Placeholder", @class = "SlectBox"})
```

where `FossilTypes` is a `List`. Chosen values will be written into this `List`.